Joining a thread started by a DLL prior to program termination on Windows
Background
I am using the miniaudio library to implement the audio module in the open-source SFML 3.x library.
As an attempt to simplify our audio resource management, I removed run-time reference counting in lieu of a simpler static manager object (see SFML/pull/2974).
My changes caused problems on Windows: any application using the audio module freezes on termination. After some investigation by @binary1248 and some further tests by myself we realized that the problem is due to how Windows handles atexit and thread termination when building as a DLL (shared library). See this article for details.
Basically, as part of process termination procedure, the Win32 runtime will forcefully terminate any remaining thread without joining them nor sending a thread-detach notification. This means that trying to cleanup miniaudio resources via atexit (which is how C++'s static object destructors are invoked) will result in a program hanging on a conditional variable wait in miniaudio's internals (ma_event_wait(&pDevice->stopEvent) inside ma_engine_uninit), because pDevice->thread was terminated and there was never a chance to signal the stop event.
As a workaround, I've tried checking if the thread is still alive prior to waiting using this solution that suggests it's sufficient to check WaitForSingleObject(threadHandle, 0) == WAIT_TIMEOUT. While this solved the problem on my machine, it didn't help on other Windows setups, and I believe it's undefined behavior anyway.
I would like to cleanly join miniaudio's internal threads before the program terminates. How can I do that?
The problem
As far as I understand, this is what happens:

SFML's shared DLL initalizes miniaudio, which internally spawns some worker threads.
Upon the process termination, the process's atexit function stack is processed.

There is nothing useful here, because miniaudio cleanup is registered on SFML's shared DLL atexit function stack.


ExitProcess is called and all threads except the main one are forcefully terminated without any thread-detach notification.

This includes the miniaudio worker threads.


The SFML DLL is unloaded and processes its own atexit function stack, which invokes miniaudio's cleanup routine.

This is the problem!
Now it's too late for the cleanup routine to join the worker threads, so it will indefinitely hang waiting on a condition variable that doesn't exist anymore.



The question
Is it possible, even by modifying miniaudio itself, to cleanly join the worker threads upon program termination, even if these threads were started from a shared library?
Basically, is it possible to invoke miniaudio's cleanup routine before ExitProcess takes place?
If not, is it still possible to somehow achieve the desired result without requiring the application developer to manually invoke the cleanup function at the end of their main?
Example
// main.cpp 
#include <windows.h>
#include "dll.h"
 
int main()
{
    std::cout << "enter main()\n";

    miniaudioSetup();
    Sleep(100);

    std::cout << "exit main()\n";
}

// dll.cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
 
void miniaudioSetup()
{
    std::cout << "enter miniaudioSetup()\n";
    
    atexit(&miniaudioCleanup);
    // ...call `ma_engine_init` here...
    
    std::cout << "exit miniaudioSetup()\n";
}
 
static void miniaudioCleanup()
{
    std::cout << "enter miniaudioCleanup()\n";

    // ...call `ma_engine_uninit` here...
    // >>> PROGRAM HANGS HERE, INSIDE `ma_engine_uninit` <<< 

    std::cout << "exit miniaudioCleanup()\n";
}

The above code will never print "exit miniaudioCleanup()". The likely output will be:

enter main()
enter miniaudioSetup()
exit miniaudioSetup()
exit main()
enter miniaudioCleanup()



atexit is too late. You have to have a shutdown function that the program calls before terminating.

If you connect the thread to a Python object, you could perform the shutdown from its __del__ method.

who start thread no matter. you try wait from DLL_PROCESS_DETACH for event which working thread never set, because it already terminated. you really need export some function from dll, for exe call it for cleanup, or you can use RtlDllShutdownInProgress() in self dll and if true - not wait.

so you need or have functions like GdiplusStartup / GdiplusShutdown in self dll and cleanup resources in "GdiplusShutdown" ( of course name will be on your choice) or check for RtlDllShutdownInProgress() and not wait in this case. destructors and registered atexit in dll, called under loader lock, so at all wait here need very "carefully" and better not wait at all ( do this in another place)

@RaymondChen: so is there absolutely no way of achieving what I want without requiring manual intervention from the application developer?

There is no way to intercept ExitProcess. A popular solution is simply to do nothing at process termination. All your threads have been terminated, and you don't know what state they were in anyway. (They might have been in the middle of updating some shared data structure, which is now corrupted.)

but what answer you want ? from DLL_PROCESS_DETACH on process exit - already threads was killed, but you can detect this and not wait. also your code anyway containing bug- in case dll will be unloaded, without process exit, dll can be unloaded before work thread exit - you not add reference to lib on thread create. you can hook  ExitProcess if want got notified about this. you can say to clients of dll - call some cleanup api before process terminate


The above code will never print "exit miniaudioCleanup()".

I guess the reason here is that miniaudioSetup is defined within the DLL, and thus the callback would be registered to the DLL's atexits, which are called after ExitProcess.
As the document of ExitProcess says, the first thing it does is to shutdown all other threads, so the main idea here is to put the cleanup procedure in some place other than the DLL's unload routine. You can export a function similar to this anywhere inside sfml-audio:
#if defined(WIN32) && !defined(SFML_STATIC)

SFML_AUDIO_API void StopAudioEngine() {
    auto engine = sf::priv::AudioDevice::get().getEngine();
    // I think this is a better choice than `ma_engine_uninit`
    // as this function is allowed to be called multiple times
    // on the same `engine`, without releasing its memory resources
    ma_engine_stop(engine);
}

#endif

and have the user call this function on the last line of main. Or, better yet, you can write a global variable that links to main directly, and register the exit procedure during that global's initialization:
// place this snippet inside a header that `main.cpp` includes
// ... or anywhere that would be eventually statically linked to `main`
struct CleanAudio {
private:
    struct Impl {
        Impl() {
            extern SFML_API_IMPORT void StopAudioEngine();

            std::atexit([] { StopAudioEngine(); });
        }
    };

    static inline Impl inst{};
};

Doing so would register the callback into every module that includes it, including the one main resides in. When main returns, the process's atexits would be called, stopping threads inside miniaudio before ExitProcess getting called.
This method may not work when sfml-audio is dynamically linked to some library, and that library itself is dynamically linked to main, without exporting sfml-audio headers to it.

There're other possible solutions I can think about. The first one, which I haven't done any experiment about yet, is to wrap your static object in some kind of ManuallyDrop struct (like the one in Rust), and call its destructor manually somewhere before ExitProcess (or don't call it at all, just let the OS do all kinds of cleanup stuff). The second one is to manually unload the sfml-audio DLL manually before ExitProcess does its job. I tried, but I failed, as it seems there's some mystical mechanism on dllimported DLLs that keeps their refcount greater than zero. The last one is to invoke TerminateProcess directly during shutdown when miniaudio is run inside a DLL. Well, this solves deadlock problem, but surely has nothing to do with "clean" or "elegant exit".

This pretty much exchanges a hang for a crash during shutdown.

@IInspectable Why would it cause a crash? I don't get it.
